# How can i disallow mp3 downloading while still allowing an HTML5 player to access and play the file?

Tags: .htaccess, permissions

How can i disallow mp3 downloading while still allowing an HTML5 player to access and play the file?

I have situation wherein an HTML5 player needs to play sample mp3 files from a specified dir. but i don’t want end users to be able to access & download these same file via the browser window.

How can this be accomplished with file permissions or an .htaccess file or both?

So far i’ve tried disallowing dir browsing via .htaccess but that doesn’t work. users can still load an individual file in the browser window.